# Minimum Order by Weight

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, customer-attribute

I have a store which sells spices. We need customer to order more than 500gm of spices. 
Whats the best way to checkout from cart by minimum weight of the product. 
Eg I dont want the order if the amount of spices is under 500gm

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried Shopping Cart Price Rules?
please try this
Also check,  "**System > Configuration > Inventory > Product Stock Options" > "Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart"**

Comment: Shopping cart rules has checkout by min & max price. Min & max quantity.

Comment: I need the checkout option to be available by minimum weight.